# CGI::Session Randomly Logging Users Out

Tags: perl, session, authentication, cgi

Here is my authentication logic:

```
sub user_logon {
my ($dbh, $cgi, $cache, $logout) = @_;

#use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
#Log::Log4perl->easy_init($DEBUG);

my $session = new CGI::Session("driver:MySQL", $cgi, {Handle=>$dbh});

$session->expires("+3h");
my $auth = new CGI::Session::Auth::DBI({
    CGI             => $cgi,
    Session         => $session,
    IPAuth          => 1,
    DBHandle        => $dbh,
    #Log             => 1,
});

if($logout) {
    $auth->logout();
}
else {
    $auth->authenticate();

    if($auth->loggedIn) {
        my $user = Cherry::Schema::ResultSet::Employee::get_employee($dbh, $cache, { number => $auth->{userid} });

        if (!$user->{active}) {
            return { error => $user->{name} . ' is not an active employee.' };
        }

        $user->{cookie} = $auth->sessionCookie();
        return $user;
    }
    elsif($cgi->param('action') eq 'logon') {
        if($cgi->param('log_username') && $cgi->param('log_username')) {
            return { error => 'Your username and/or password did not match.' };
        }
        elsif(!$cgi->param('log_username') || !$cgi->param('log_username')) {
            return { error => 'Please enter a username and a password.' };
        }
    }
    else {
        return { error => 'You are not logged in' };
    }
}
}

sub handle_authentication {
my ($dbh, $cache, $config, $params, $cgi) = @_;

if(($cgi->param('auth') || '') eq 'super_user') { # for automation
    return;
}

if(($params->{action} || '') eq 'log_off') {
    user_logon($dbh, $cgi, $cache, 1); # 1 means log out
    login_form($config, 'Successfully logged out', $params->{login_url}, $params->{title});
}

my $user = user_logon($dbh, $cgi, $cache);

if(exists $user->{error}) {
    login_form($config, $user->{error}, $params->{login_url}, $params->{title});
}
elsif($user->{number}) {
    return $user;
}

}
```

Then in my code, every time I print a header, it looks something like this:

```
my $user = Cherry::Authentication::handle_authentication(
$dbh,
$cache,
\%config,
{
    action      => $FORM{action},
    username   => $FORM{log_username},
    password    => $FORM{log_password},
    auth        => $FORM{auth}
},
$cgi
);
print header( 
    -type   => 'application/json',
    -cookie => $user->{cookie}
);
```

The problem is that this code seems to work very well about 80% of the time. The other 20%, users are getting kicked out (and not after being stale for 3 hours).

Are there any obvious flaws in this code? Have I left any crucial code out?

If you feel is there not enough information here to give a viable solution, do you have any general suggestions on what can be done to troubleshoot these types of issues?

Comment: Can you look at the headers the users are sending? Maybe the cookie is going away. Also, are there multiple database servers involved? I've seen this with a web server cluster where the session files went into the local file system instead of the shared one, but you don't have files, you have a db. There might be something similar happening. Is it happening to all users or just some? What are their characteristics? Can you find common identifiers to group them? I'd first look at the files/sessions. Keep an eye on the table, look for when the same user makes a second session.

Comment: I agree with what simbabque said. With the current info I would say add more logging. If the log out function is getting triggered, you should log, when, and by who, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this particular problem, there was some code in play that I was unaware of.

```
$cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(
    -name       => $session->name, # problem line
    -value      => $session->id,   # problem line
    -expires    => '+1y',
    -path       => '/',
    -secure     => 0,
);

my @header = (
    -cookie => $cookie,
    -type => 'text/html',
    -status     => $status
);

print $cgi->header( @header );
```

The lines with the comments **#problem line** were assigning a new session even when one already existed.

I installed [Fiddler HTTP Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) on the user's computer that seemed to have the issue the most. Then, once the user was unexpectedly logged out, I reviewed the logs. I was able to find a correlation between the user visiting one url, and the unexpected log out on the next request.